# Remove lines from datagrid

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid

Can we remove the lines  between every row of datagrid? 
so that it look like listview (so that only data should be there no lines in between two rows)

Comment: Have you tried to set `GridLinesVisibility` to `None`?

Comment: can you also tell how to remove  the first small column that occurs in all rows?

Comment: @RATHI, `HeadersVisibility = Column` or `None`.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

You can toggle the visibility of the grid lines with `GridLinesVisibility`. To hide them, just set it to `None`

```
<DataGrid ...
          GridLinesVisibility="None"/>
```

Comment: Using the designer view in VS 2015, you can achieve the same effect by setting the properties: "CellBorderStyle" and "GridColor" and "RowHeadersVisible"

Comment: Is it possible to remove only horizontal lines from DataGrid?

Comment: @Roxy'Pro: Yes, use `GridLinesVisibility="Vertical"`

Comment: Is it possible to remove the Gridlines of a specific column in a datagrid? GridLines="None" removes the gridlines in the entire table. Let say I have 4 columns and only want to remove the gridlines of one specific column?

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:DataGrid ... GridLines="None">
<Columns>
</Columns>
</asp:DataGrid>
```